# show success message in $http response

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to show one `success` message in http response for 3secs,then I need to redirect the page.
This is my code

```
<body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 alert alert-success" ng-show="successMessage">
            <strong></strong>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var app = angular
        .module("myApp",[])
        .controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {

            $http.post('/user/userList').then(function (response) {
                $scope.successMessage = "Form submitted successfully";
                $scope.successMessage = true;
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.successMessage = false;
                }, 5000);

                //growl.success('Form submitted successfully!', { title: 'Success!' });
                window.location = '/user/userList';
            })

        })

</script>
```

But Its not showing the message in my `success box`.It just shows the empty success box for only 1 sec and immediately redirects the page.

Comment: You cannot use same model for two different data-types simultaneously.

Comment: **My suggestion**  is : you can go with a confirm box to show a confirmation message before redirect to next page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your var name in JS. You are using the same variable for setting the message and for `ng-show`

**JS**:

```
$http.post('/user/userList').then(function (response) {
        $scope.successMessage = "Form submitted successfully";
        $scope.successMessagebool = true;
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.successMessagebool = false;
             window.location = '/user/userList';
        }, 5000);
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 alert alert-success" ng-show="successMessagebool ">
        <strong>{{successMessage }}</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: `$http(httpRequest).then(function (response) {
                                $("#deleteProject").modal('hide');
                                $scope.successMessage = "user deleted successfully";
                                $scope.successMessageBox = true;
                                $timeout(function () {
                                    $scope.successMessageBox = false;
                                    $scope.getList();
                                }, 500);
                              
                            })`Its not hiding until I refresh the page.

Comment: Is it working now? Don't mix jQuery with angular. It is better if you show the success message in a popup and hide it when you close the popup.

Comment: sorry I forgot to inject `$timeout`.Its working now:-)

Answer (score 1):

you can try shifting your window.location inside timeout

```
                               $timeout(function () {
                                    $scope.successMessage = false;
                                 window.location = '/user/userList';
                                }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

$timeout is an asynchronous method which doesn't hold the process and keep other code wait to finish.
It execute immediately next part of your code.

in your case it will redirect to new location `'/user/userList'`

put your redirection inside timeout function.

```
 $timeout(function () {
                             $scope.successMessage = false;
                             window.location = '/user/userList';
                       },5000);
```

*Hope it is clear now.*

Answer (score 1):

In Angular application, `ng-show` wants expression based on that it can hide and show element. You have given 'string'.

Solution:
Please use conditional variable like 'isDisplay' or something like that. That will used for hide and show your element.
You also need to print your message using `{{successMessage}}`. For your case `<strong>{{successMessage}}</strong>` This will print message. Now you just need to set 'isDisplay' to hide and show message. Your final code will be:

```
$http.post('/user/userList').then(function (response) {
    $scope.successMessage = "Form submitted successfully";
    $scope.isDisplay = true;
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.isDisplay = false;
        window.location = '/user/userList';
    }, 5000);
});
```

Your html will be:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 alert alert-success ng-hide" ng-show="isDisplay"><strong>{{successMessage}}</strong></div>
```